# Mark packages to be installed and run aptitude in interactive mode

Tags: debian, aptitude

I want to install series of packages. Selecting all of them in TUI is inconvenient. But if there're any conflicts, resolving them in interactive mode is much easier.

Is it possible to mark packages to be installed with command line and then run aptitude in interactive mode to resolve conflicts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just found the solution:

```
aptitude --schedule-only install <package1> <package2> && aptitude
```